# npm: ENOENT no such file or directory

Tags: npm

I've looked at a few answers but cannot resolve this. I've completely removed Node from my system and reinstalled, but I still can't install any packages.

I get the following error every time:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mattsaunders/Documents/package.json'

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mattsaunders/Documents/package.json'
```

npm -v shows 5.5.1

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not calling `install` from an npm project, so it can't find your `package.json` file

Comment: I don't understand. If I navigate to my Documents folder and run "npm install --save redux" I get the same error. I've never needed to create a package file before. Shouldn't the install do this itself?

Comment: When you use the `--save` flag, that's telling npm to add this entry to your package.json file. If you're not in an npm project, there will be no package.json. If you want to create one, you can use `npm init`

Comment: Okay, what about this one: npm install recharts, without the save flag. how am I to tell if a package will create its own json file?

Comment: To my knowledge, unless you use `--g`, which is the global flag, you will need be within an npm project, with a valid package.json. If you use the `--g` flag, it will add it to your global node_modules

Comment: A +1 'cause you just made me realize that modules are installed for each project (which is pretty lame in itself)